# Scatter/gather socket write in Python

Tags: python, sockets

In POSIX C we can use `writev` to write multiple arrays at once to a file descriptor. This is useful when you have to concatenate multiple buffers in order to form a single message to send through a socket (think of a HTTP header and body, for instance). This way I don't need to call `send` twice, once for the header and once for the body (what prevent the messages to be split in different frames on the wire), nor I need to concatenate the buffers before sending.

My question is, is there a Python equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is in the upcoming [Python 3.3](http://python.org/download/releases/3.3.0/), now in alpha testing.  See [`socket.sendmsg`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendmsg).

Answer (score 2):

1. Python supports `os.writev()` as well as `sendmsg()`. These functions are atomic, so are equivalent of calling `write()` and `send()` respectively with concatenated buffer.
2. There is `TCP_CORK`. You may say kernel not to send partial frames until un-corked.

Using either technique, you may have control over partial TCP frames.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12423944)

Comment: @gonz I answered to the question. I'm not critique or request clarification.

Comment: The original answer I reviewed (before your edit) was "Also, Python supports os.writev()" which appeared to be a comment expanding on the answer by Ned. Now it looks much better, thanks for improving it! +1