# boost::system::error_code::message() throwing access violation exception with boost::asio socket

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio, c++builder-xe4

I am implementing a client application that has to make a small number of socket connections to hardware devices. I have broken down the problem to the following small code subset

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
std::string str_message = ec.message();  // no access violation before connect()
std::string str_port = "502";
std::string str_ip = "192.168.12.198";

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(),str_ip,str_port);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket s(io_service);

ec = s.connect(*iterator,ec);
if (ec)
{
    // connection error of some kind.
    std::string str_debug = ec.message();  // BANG!!!!

}
```

I am using Embarcadero RAD studio XE4 C++ Builder and when I run the above code in the main VCL thread it works fine. When I run it with multiple connections, I have the above code running in multiple instances of the `TThread` class and that is when I get into problems with an access violation - it appears that when the `error_code` is modified by the `connect` call, the internal member `m_cat` of the `error_code` instance becomes NULL and so when I call `message()` I get the access violation. This happens even when I just have a single background thread running.

Is it possible that my code above is simply not thread safe in the way I need to use it? I have tried to find out why this code won't run in a background thread, but cannot find anything about it.

The boost version I am running is 1.50 as this is the integrated version that is used for building 64 bit applications in RAD studio.

Has anyone else encountered this issue in a multithreaded setting (in Embarcadero or otherwise) and if so how did you resolve it? Or is this class simply not safe to use in a multithreaded way?

Comment: Two questions: First, when you say "having it run in different threads" does every thread have its own io_service? And i assume they have different address, port combinations to connect to? Second, if you know address and port, you can just create an endpoint yourself instead of resolving a query. Have you checked the iterator to actually contain any endpoints? And lastly: I believe when using an iterator, you should use the non-member `connect()` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/connect.html However that could be wrong.

Comment: @DeVadder Yes each thread is connecting to a distinct client machine and each thread has its own io_service. I will take a look at the link you provided. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is kind of a long shot, but it might be worth a try:

The `system::error_code` is made up of two entries: An error value and a category. The error value is basically just an `int`, but the category is a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). This is required because error categories are compared for equality based on pointer identities (ie. two categories are equal if and only if they point to the *same* category object).

The problem is that initialization of the category Singleton might not be thread-safe. Asio uses the `system_category`, which is implemented in `boost/libs/system/src/error_code.cpp`. For 1.50 the implementation looks like this:

```
BOOST_SYSTEM_DECL const error_category & system_category() BOOST_SYSTEM_NOEXCEPT
{
  static const system_error_category  system_category_const;
  return system_category_const;
}
```

This is guaranteed to be thread-safe on C++11 conforming compilers, but if your compiler does not implement [thread-safe initialization of function-scope statics](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2660.htm), this might break. You can easily verify this by tracing calls to this function and see if you observe a potential race.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is the most useful suggestion I have had so far. I will take a look into this.

Answer (score 1):

In multiple examples, they call io_service->run() in a thread:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/futures/daytime_client.cpp

I liked this one, with a ThreadPool:
[Thread pool using boost asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215395/thread-pool-using-boost-asio)

Are you sure io_service->run() is called somewhere?

Comment: I was under the impression that that was required for async sockets rather than synchronous

Answer (score 1):

You must always be sure that `iterator != boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator()`.

From boost docs:

> A default constructed iterator represents the end of the list.

I bet it's the problem, `connect()` just breaks the stack due to invalid endpoint iterator.