# boost::io_service post using a lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, lambda, cuda

This question relates to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831562/boost-thread-worker-object-re-use-after-thread-has-finished/33832638#33832638).

I've implemented the code published there by Richard Hodges.
The code published works for me when I use `g++ (Debian 4.8.4-1) 4.8.4`.

However, the implementation is part of a CUDA library, and I am stuck with CUDA 6.5 which unofficially supported C++11 features.

When I use the code Richard posted:

```
template <class F>
void submit( F&& f)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_cvm);
    ++ _tasks;
    lock.unlock();
    _io_service.post(
    [this, f = std::forward<F>(f)]
                     {
                         f();
                         reduce();
                     });
}
```

I get an error: `error: expected a "]"` referring to the lambda line.
This makes me think that the header is not being parsed properly.
I tried without the template, just passing a reference to my worker class, and without the forwarding.

```
void submit( trainer & job)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_cvm);
    ++ _tasks;
    lock.unlock();
    _io_service.post([this,&]
                     {
                         job();
                         reduce();
                     });
}
```

And I got `error: an enclosing-function local variable cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list`.

So I explicitly added both `this` and `job`:

```
void submit( trainer & job)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_cvm);
    ++ _tasks;
    lock.unlock();
    _io_service.post([this,&job]
                     {
                         job();
                         reduce();
                     });
}
```

At which point, I got stuck at error:

`error: could not convert ‘{{((cuANN::trainer_pool*)this)->cuANN::trainer_pool::_io_service}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘boost::asio::io_service::work’
     boost::asio::io_service::work _work { _io_service };`

FYI, `cuANN::trainer_pool` is the `worker_pool` in Richard's example, and the thread pool implementation, and `_io_service` is simply a member of the `class trainer_pool`:

```
class trainer_pool
{   
public:
    trainer_pool ( unsigned int max_threads );
    void start();
    void wait();
    void stop(); 
    void thread_proc();
    void reduce();
    void submit( trainer & job);

private:
    unsigned int _max_threads_;
    boost::asio::io_service _io_service;
    boost::asio::io_service::work _work { _io_service };
    std::vector<std::thread> _threads;
    std::condition_variable _cv;
    std::mutex _cvm;
    size_t _tasks = 0;
};
```

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I do it using std::bind or boost::bind instead of using a lambda?

PS: the code on http://ideone.com/g38Z4H is my skeleton for g++ (which works). 
The http://ideone.com/d7Nkop saved as `host.cu` also showcases the issue.

`nvcc -std=c++11 host.cu -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lpthread -o host`

Comment: Can you provide a short code that is complete (so I don't have to go digging around to try and guess at what you are compiling) along with the exact compile command you are using?

Comment: Is this code to be used in device code? If not then separate compilation of host and device code might be an option.

Comment: @havogt this is to be run on host only, but I'm building it as a library.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I'll do that asap.

Comment: I can't compile "Richard's code" using `g++ -std=c++11 ...` using gnu 4.8.3.  It throws compile errors for me around `string_literals`.  Do you need 4.8.4 for that?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Yes, the ldone example I've posted uses printf instead so it works with 4.8.3

Comment: I can't compile your code either with g++.  boost 1.54 won't work?

Comment: That's bizarre, it works with g++ and I am also using boost 1.54. What's the error you get?

Comment: The code compiles for me with g++ 4.8.1 and boost 1.53

Comment: Never mind, I made a mistake.  I can compile your code with g++ 4.8.3 and boost 1.54, but I do get the error around `]` with nvcc ver. 7.5.  So I think it is an nvcc compiler bug.  I will file a bug internally at NVIDIA, but I don't have any immediate workaround suggestions for you, other than the one suggested by @havogt  Your objection about this being a library is not clear to me as to why that would be a problem.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I just made a new ideone example: http://ideone.com/d7Nkop  This one uses the same code I've posted in my question and I got the same error. I am guessing its an issue of nvcc and c++11? I am also compiling seperately in cmake, but I 'll' try and see if I can use g++ without nvcc for this particular file. 
How can I use std::bind, or boost::bind instead in order to avoid the lambda altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. NVCC and CUDA works fine with the lambdas.

The offending line was in the header:

```
boost::asio::io_service::work _work { _io_service };
```

CUDA 6.5 does not like the initializer list.
Moving it to the constructor:

```
trainer_pool (unsigned int max_threads)
:_max_threads_(max_threads), _work(_io_service)
{}
```

Seems to have fixed the error and the code now compiles.
Many thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 2):

this construct:

```
[this, f = std::forward<F>(f)]
```

is c++14 and won't compile in c++11.

using `[this, &]` would be a mistake since there's no guarantee that the function object will still exist (you captured it by reference)

in c++11 consider `[this, f]` to take a copy.

edit: just realised that job is mutable, therefore:

```
void submit(trainer & job)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_cvm);
    ++ _tasks;
    lock.unlock();
    _io_service.post([this,job]()->void mutable
                     {
                         job();
                         reduce();
                     });
}
```

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the issue still persists if I copy it by value within the lambda. I think its a problem with cuda 6.5/nvcc.
Do you know how I can do the same using bind?

Comment: bind would be complicated but you could just define a local structure that has a call operator (basically hand-coding the lambda)

Comment: You mean that I need a wrapper for the reference to both `_io_service` and the thread worker? It seems to me like I have no other choice since I can't get lambdas to compile.

Comment: ah - i've just realised that your trainer object is non-const. that is a problem.

Comment: see edit. you need to make the lambda mutable if your function object is mutable.

Comment: I'm afraid I am still getting the same error:  `error: could not convert ‘{{((cuANN::trainer_pool*)this)->cuANN::trainer_pool::_io_service}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘boost::asio::io_service::work’
     boost::asio::io_service::work _work { _io_service };`

This seems to suggest that there is an issue with casting `this` inside the lambda and not the worker object `job`?