# How to completely convert boost::asio code to C++11/asio without boost for deadline_timer?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

My goal is to have my project to use the "[asio](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asio/)" library without Boost, but use C++11.  The example is to convert this [server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/timeouts/server.cpp) code to use Timeout.

Here is what I did:

1. `boost::bind` -> `std::bind`, `_1` -> `std::placeholders::_1`
2. most `boost::asio::xxx` -> `asio::xxx`
3. `boost::system::error_code` -> `asio::error_code`

Now, there is 12 errors left all about deadline_timer :

```
deadline_timer input_deadline_;
input_deadline_.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);
...
void check_deadline(deadline_timer* deadline)
{
    ...

    if (deadline->expires_at() <= deadline_timer::traits_type::now())
```

What is the correct code to use?  I am using GCC 4.9.1/2, and newly downloaded asio library 1.10.6.

Comment: Where is `ASIO` coming from? It's certainly not the C++11 standard library

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/asio/files/asio/1.10.6%20%28Stable%29/

Comment: Why not simply ask [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29661788/560648)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `high_resolution_timer` instead, which uses `std::chrono` on C++11 compilers:

```
#if defined(GENERATING_DOCUMENTATION)
/// Typedef for a timer based on the high resolution clock.
/**
 * This typedef uses the C++11 @c &lt;chrono&gt; standard library facility, if
 * available. Otherwise, it may use the Boost.Chrono library. To explicitly
 * utilise Boost.Chrono, use the basic_waitable_timer template directly:
 * @code
 * typedef basic_waitable_timer<boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock> timer;
 * @endcode
 */
typedef basic_waitable_timer<
    chrono::high_resolution_clock>
  high_resolution_timer;
#elif defined(ASIO_HAS_STD_CHRONO)
typedef basic_waitable_timer<
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>
  high_resolution_timer;
#elif defined(ASIO_HAS_BOOST_CHRONO)
typedef basic_waitable_timer<
    boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock>
  high_resolution_timer;
#endif

} // namespace asio
```

Comment: Thanks.  How to do convert the boost::posix_time::pos_infin?

Comment: What are you using it for?

Comment: here is the code in the server example:  input_deadline_.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);

Comment: `hrt.expires_at(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point::max());`?

Comment: I think you are right. Is it correct to use this: deadline->expires_at() <= std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) {// was deadline_timer::traits_type::now()